# My NIntegrate expression returns a wildly inaccurate value

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I am trying to integrate a function using `NIntegrate`:

```
a1 = 0.00221856
b = 0.0990293
h = 100.0
a1 NIntegrate[Exp[-b * (z-h)^2]* z, {z, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 4]

(* Out: 6.202e-25 *)
```

I have also computed the same integral analytically and the answer is 1.25. 
In *Mathematica*, if I replace the limits of integration as `{z, 0, 200}` in place of `{z, 0, Infinity}`, then I get the right answer. I am confused as to what is going on.

Comment: please post valid Mathematica code. The above hard to read. What is `h = 100.0 i11 = a1xNintegrate`?  and `a1xNintegrate` ?

Comment: Please also format your code and check your spelling (`Nintegrate` is misspelled; `a1xNintegrate` should be `a1*NIntegrate`, etc).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the function you are integrating:

```
Plot[Exp[-b*(z - h)^2]*z, {z, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again for reference, your integral can be calculated analytically, as you mentioned yourself:

```
a1 = Rationalize[0.00221856, 0];
b = Rationalize[0.0990293, 0];
h = 100;
a1 Integrate[Exp[-b*(z - h)^2]*z, {z, 0, Infinity}]
N[%]

(* Out:
-(13866/25) Sqrt[(2 Pi)/4951465] (-2 + GammaRegularized[-(1/2), 990293/1000])
1.24958
*)
```

Numerically, once you remove the `AccuracyGoal` option you have in your code, **`NIntegrate` works, but returns a warning**:

```
a1 = 0.00221856;
b = 0.0990293;
h = 100.0;
a1 NIntegrate[Exp[-b*(z - h)^2]*z, {z, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: NIntegrate error]

```
(* Out: 1.24958 *)
```

The warning suggests that the routine needs to perform more bisections than the default value of `MaxRecursion` will allow.

The natural approach will then be to **increase the value of `MaxRecursion`**. The following, for example, executes immediately and without warnings to yield the correct value:

```
a1 NIntegrate[Exp[-b*(z - h)^2]*z, {z, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 20]

(* Out: 1.24958 *)
```

---

Notice that `AccuracyGoal` can be difficult to use; for instance, the "Details and Options" section of the [documentation for `AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html) mentions that "In most cases, you must set `WorkingPrecision` to be at least as large as `AccuracyGoal`." In this case, even setting a much higher working precision does not solve the problem.